# Does secure boot + shim protect against evil maid?

Tags: secure-boot

I'm setting up my arch linux to dual boot with windows and secure boot enabled. As far as I have understood secure boot, the goal is to prevent an attacker from modifying the boot manager and/or kernel. For windows, this also works when I leave my laptop unattended as a modified boot manager would not be signed with Microsoft's key.

Almost all linux distros use [shim](https://github.com/rhboot/shim), so do I. After setup and reboot I need to enroll the hash of the GRUB boot manager. So far so good. Then I simulate an attack by changing a byte in the grub binary and reboot. I am again prompted by to enroll its hash and can do so without any hassle.

So how does this improve anything if a security violation can easily be "fixed" by enrolling a new hash? Is there something I have misunderstood?

Comment: I'm not sure why this was down-voted, as it's an interesting topic. I did some looking and it looks like it is going to be susceptible to the evil maid attack regardless. Look up "EvilAbigail" and "de-LUKS". With the latter, visit their GitHub page, scroll down, and read up on possible defenses for the evil maid attack. They're not comforting.

Comment: @KGIII Hi. Searching for “"EvilAbigail" "de-LUKS"” in Google shows nothing except your comment.

Comment: https://www.digitalmunition.me/evilabigail-automated-evil-maid-attack-linux/ https://github.com/nyxxxie/de-LUKS @beroal - I'd suggest finding a better search engine.

Comment: Also, I just used Google for both of those terms and the results were there. I'm not sure what you're doing wrong, or why you'd pretend otherwise.

Comment: @KGIII Probably because “de-LUKS” and “EvilAbigail” do not occur together on any webpage. And my search string for “de-LUKS” was in quotes: this is needed for terms with hyphens. Thank you for the links.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Secure boot does not in itself protect against an attacker with physical access to the machine. I recommend using a password to protect against unauthorized access to the firmware setup. The primary goal of secure boot is to prevent malware from inserting compromised kernels and boot loaders.

A user with physical access can enroll new public keys (i.e. store them in nonvolatile storage controlled by the firmware). These public keys are used to verify the integrity of the bootloader, the kernel, and anything else that is run at boot time. After enrolling a new key, the attacker can then install a new kernel, which is signed with the attacker's private key. Or an attacker with physical access can disable secure boot altogether.

But, here's the crux: new keys can only be added if the person doing so has physical access to the screen and can enter the firmware setup. Physical access is *required* to be able to replace or add new keys. Secure boot is designed to protect against scenarios where an attacker tries to modify critical system files by breaking into the computer when the system has *already been started*. This break-in can happen via the network, or using a trojan horse program the legitimate user is tricked to run. Even with secure boot active, the attacker may be able to modify the kernel image, but the firmware refuses to start the kernel at the next boot, because the signature does not match.

So, UEFI Secure Boot does have its uses, but here's an additional point to consider. Since computers are shipped with Microsoft's and the hardware manufacturer's keys preinstalled, it is not under your control which binaries are able to run at boot time on your computer. Bugs have been detected in signed GRUB images that can be used to circumvent secure boot. Microsoft and hardware vendors may be signing all kinds of binaries left and right, and you have no way of knowing.

The solution to this problem is to get rid of all the firmware keys and replace them with your own. This way only you can sign binaries that are allowed to run (at boot time) on your computer. But beware: there are reports of some computers that require special drivers to boot, and these drivers are signed with keys that require the original public keys to be present, or the machine won't boot.

Comment: Secure Boot is referenced with regard to evil maid prevention e.g. in the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evil_maid_attack#Prevention). I understand, of course, that I have to secure the deactivation of secure boot using a password. As far as I have understood the mechanism, though, if that is done only signed binaries will be executed. So how would an attacker replace any of them?

Comment: I'm hoping you're able to point me into the right direction for my follow-up question. In the meantime I'll accept your answer, as it confirms what I have already suspected: Secure Boot + Shim only prevents an attacker having already gained access to the running system from persistently compromising the kernel by making changes apparent.

Comment: Whoa thanks for the awesome update! You're saying "physical access to the screen and *can enter the firmware setup*" so am I right in assuming if the firmware setup is password protected, this attack route is eliminated?
Otherwise I still don't see much of a point to secure boot. If an attacker can change my kernel at runtime, they have to have root access already, which I would consider compromised anyhow.

Comment: Secure boot can prevent a stealth attack, where a modified kernel could be continuously leaking information without being detected. I guess the designers of secure boot has envisioned it as just the first link in the chain of crypto protected binaries, starting from boot, then drivers and applications. The latter part has to be implemented by the operating system, but secure boot is required as a foundation, otherwise the scheme can easily be circumvented. "The chain is only as strong as its weakest link."

Comment: Right. You mean, an attacker could simply modify all the other binaries on the system? I didn't mention that I intend to encrypt my system partition. I kinda thought this was a no-brainer in 2020, but of course, I was not clear, sorry for that.

Comment: My comment was just a reflection on what I guess would be the development of secure boot. Btw, file system encryption solves a different problem. File system encryption can be a good measure against an evil maid, but does not protect your system against attack (e g. binary file modification) when the system is running.

Comment: What if I unscrew your unattended laptop, swap your motherboard, put key2 in the swapped motherboard, put key2-signed key-logger-infested boot loader in your ssd, then put everything back together? Secure boot's safety relies on the motherboard being authentic.